# Is there a way to pass in variable to <div> id in django template?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I am new to the Django template language and I am playing around with bootstrap collapses to display my items. Below is my code:

```
{% for item in items %}
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          {{item.item_name}}
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        {{item.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is taken from the Bootstrap documentation for collapse, [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/). In this implementation, all of the items passed in would have the same id, collapseOne. So whenever I click on an item, any item, it would collapse/uncollapse every item on the page. I've tried `id="collapse{{item.item_name}}"` but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to pass in variables in <div> id?

Comment: what exactly does not work

Comment: `data-target="#collapseOne"` also needs updating to match => `data-target="#collapse{{item.item_name}}"`

Comment: So I have my items displayed on the webpage. Whenever I click on an item to open it, it opens every item on the page at the same time because all of the ids are the same. I want to name each id uniquely so it toggles collapse only on one item

Comment: @Ben I've tried that and every id that's supposed to match it, still doesn't work

Comment: did you change `aria-controls="collapseOne"` as well? (`aria-controls="collapse{{item.item_name}}" `)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
{% for item in items %}
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading{{forloop.counter}}">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{forloop.counter}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{forloop.counter}}">
          {{item.item_name}}
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse{{forloop.counter}}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading{{forloop.counter}}" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        {{item.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language